# FTP Upload--ASCII mode--a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a FTP upload program for text files. However I'm getting this error:

```
builtins.TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'.
```

I am using Python 3.6.

Here is my code:

```
def _upload_to_ftp(self, ftp_handle, name):

  # upload a single file to ftp directory

  with open(name,'r') as f:
    print("uploading"+name)
    filename = os.path.basename(name)
    ftp_handle.storlines('STOR %s' %filename, f)
```

I could not figure out why.

Comment: What line is causing the error? Would be best if you included the entire traceback in your question. BTW, strings are Unicode in Python 3 so that might be the cause of the issue (i.e. they're not ASCII).

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, what FTP calls text is still bytes for Python 3. Python 3 strings use Unicode characters that need to be encoded to bytes in order to be written to files and FTP deals with files. But here it is even simpler: you have just to open the local file in binary mode to have it deliver bytes instead of strings:

```
def _upload_to_ftp(self, ftp_handle, name):

  # upload a single file to ftp directory

  with open(name,'rb') as f:      # use binary mode for file
    print("uploading"+name)
    filename = os.path.basename(name)
    ftp_handle.storlines('STOR %s' %filename, f)
```

Comment: Thanks Serge, that clears it up. I was using 'w' for the ASCII FTP download and figured for upload I would use 'r' instead of 'rb'. Now I understand how python 3 deal with bytes and strings.